# swift function's default absence value

Tags: swift

[image: swift programming example codes]

This is the code that provided by apple's swift tutorial. On the 4th line, I checked and not found the usage of default absence parameter value. Could anyone explain the usage of this line

```
init(name: String, prefix: String? = nil)
```

Does that mean if I initialize the Starship like this:

```
Starship("SuperHero")
```

is ok?

I think I should initialize the Starship class like this

```
Starship(name:"SuperHero")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will be valid code.

With default value for 2nd parameter you indeed can provide only one parameter to initializer:

```
Starship(name:"SuperHero")
```

That will be identical to the following call:

```
Starship(name:"SuperHero", prefix:nil)
```

Comment: Yup, I tried it in playground, and it worked. Thx. Btw, maybe you should edit with external parameter names, that should be the perfect correct one.